# Flag rows based on criteria

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which I loop through one day at a time and determine which items from that day qualify based on specific criteria. I need to then flag those qualifying items. Dataframe:

```
        date           abc    xyz    rth
index
apple   2015-01-27     23     5712   713  
        2015-01-28     234    1357   9541
        2015-01-29     489    185    278
        2015-01-30     154    951    754
pear    2015-01-27     4786   7531   4751
        2015-01-28     476    367    45
        2015-01-29     15     37     783
        2015-01-30     489    185    421
grape   2015-01-27     2513   57     513
        2015-01-28     237    587    733
        2015-01-29     7869   472    759
        2015-01-30     489    185    278
```

For example, I need to flag each item that meets the following criteria for each date:

- abc > 50
- xyz > 700
- rth = once I have a shortlist based on the above criteria, select the single item from this shortlist which has the maximum value for rth

The output for the above criteria would be:

```
        date           abc    xyz    rth    meets_criteria
index
apple   2015-01-27     23     5712   713  
        2015-01-28     234    1357   9541   True
        2015-01-29     489    185    278
        2015-01-30     154    951    754    True
pear    2015-01-27     4786   7531   4751   True
        2015-01-28     476    367    45
        2015-01-29     15     37     783
        2015-01-30     489    185    421
grape   2015-01-27     2513   57     513
        2015-01-28     237    587    733
        2015-01-29     7869   472    759
        2015-01-30     489    185    278
```

As you can see, one item met the criteria per day on the 27th, 28th, 30th. No items met the criteria on the 29th.

So far I have done the following to be able to evaluate each day:

```
unique_dates = df['date'].unique()

for i in range(0, len(unique_dates)):
    today_df = df.loc[df['date'] == unique_dates[i]]

    today_df = today_df.loc[today_df['abc'] > 50]
    today_df = today_df.loc[today_df['xyz'] > 700]

    today_df = today_df.sort('rth')
    today_df = today_df.tail(1)
```

This gives me the qualifying item (if there is one) for each day. My problem is I can't figure out how to take the qualifying item from today_df and flag it on the correct row in the original dataframe.

Comment: does `df.loc[(df['abc']> 50) & (df['xyz']> 700), 'rth'].max(level='date')` do what you want?

Comment: Thanks, however I get the error: ValueError: level name date is not the name of the index. Also, these criteria are just an example. There may be a scenario where I need the maximum X rows for 'rth'. Not just the single maximum value. ie: in my example the last row might be today_df = today_df.tail(2) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sorted_df = df.sort_index(by = 'rth' , ascending=False)

sorted_df.groupby('date' , as_index = False).apply(meets_criteria)

def meets_criteria(df):
    # Check for each value in column whether it satisfies your condition or not , simply concatenate results into one data frame we will use this later
    criteria_df = pd.concat([df['abc'] > 50 , df['xyz'] > 700] , axis = 1)
    # we want all conditions to be met for each row this can be achieved by the next line of code
    meets_criteria = np.all(criteria_df , axis = 1)
    # slice only the data that matches your criteria 
    df_meets_criteria = df[meets_criteria]
    # this handles the case where there is matched criteria
    if len(df_meets_criteria) > 0:
        vals = np.zeros(len(df))
        vals[0] = 1
        df['meets_criteria'] = vals  
    # this handles the case where there is no matched criteria 
    else:
        df['meets_criteria'] = np.zeros(len(df))
    return df.reset_index()
```

Comment: Can you post an explanation of your code, posting code only answers is counter-productive

Comment: Thanks Nader. This works for the first two criteria. But I don't see how you determined the final criteria for 'rth'. ie: Select the maximum 'rth' value. Or select the maximum X number of 'rth' values. Your code seems to only filter for criteria on 'abc' and 'xyz'?

Comment: so you want to select only one value , which is the maximum value of `rth` ? in this case should it be `9541` ?

Comment: No, each day is evaluated separately. First 'abc' and 'xyz' are evaluated. Then out of those results (for that specific day), I need the row with the maximum 'rth' value. However that is just one example. There are cases where I need the maximum X number of 'rth' values for that day. For example, the top 2, or top 3 etc. That is why in my example for the original question, I used today_df.tail(1). That way I can not only select the maximum. Hope that makes sense in the original question?

Comment: sorry for the late reply I think I got your point , if this is the right answer for you let me know to give you some detail about how it works

Comment: Excellent, thanks. That seems to be working. Great job.